# Position a div outside the main content, undetected by horizontal scrollbar

Tags: html, scrollbar, hidden, css-position

I have a mockup of my problem at http://scottmccarthydesign.com/blocks/blocktest.html

I have 5 divs: 1. Overall content div at 600px, 2. a left rail, 3. a right rail, 4. an absolutely positioned box in the right rail, and 5. another absolutely positioned box inside the parent box.

Objective 1: Push div #5 outside of the main content div. I have accomplished this with absolute positioning and a right: -25px.

Objective 2: I don't want the browser's horizontal scroll bar to appear unless the browser window width is less than the width of the main content div (600px).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

How about adding this:

```
body { overflow-x: hidden; }    

@media screen and (max-width: 600px) {
  body { overflow-x: scroll; }
 }
```

I think it should be fairly self-explanatory ...

Disclaimer: Only tested in Opera, but I used a similar trick and IIRC that worked in all recent browsers.